# Bluetooth Discovery vs Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

So in my quest to obtain a constantly updating RSSI value, I have been forced to resort to this inefficient method.  I've tried using bluecove 2.1.1, but it's given me some library errors and runtime errors that I do not want to waste anymore time dealing with. The developers guide defines discovery as the process of scanning for nearby, discoverable devices.

Is calling the method Intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE); during this time possible?

Or must the two devices establish a connection first for the above method to have any significance?

That is, for my poll() method, could I first save the MAC address of the device in question to some variable mac_addr, save the RSSI value to some variable my_rssi, then every time poll() is called, a new scan is run, and the device whose mac address matches that of mac_addr is targeted and updates the my_rssi field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly or better, you can **only** get the RSSI value during a device discovery scan. My MSc research thesis was about that topic. This is because an RSSI value during an active connection is not reliable (due to the nature of the RSSI value itself) and hence Google Android engineers did not expose it through the API.

Advantage of this:

- You don't need an active connection and hence no pairing is required
- Since there is no "piconet" involved, the number of devices you scan is possibly infinite

Disadvantages

- Other bluetooth devices need to be discoverable (this is an issue, especially if you want to find other Android devices which have a max discoverability interval)
- Continuous device discovery scans are a heavy process -> [costs a lot of battery](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices)

The problem however with constantly executing a device discovery is that it consumes a lot of battery on the mobile device...

Comment: Thanks a lot Juri! I've spent weeks trying to find and implement an efficient way to achieve this goal, but finally I gave up. For my baby steps at Android Deving at this local university at least, inefficiency will be better than having non-functionality at least. Thanks again.

Comment: What kind of goal do you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically it will give the relative distance of an nearby bluetooth device, play an alarm at a certain threshold distance. So I have everything set up, the UI, buttons, widgets etc, playing alarm functionality, scanning functionality, connecting, etc. Just this last polling RSSI value remains to be had. I think overall the project given to me with the constraints (MUST USE BLUETOOTH on ANDROID) was flawed in this last step. Nevertheless, I intend to have at least some functionality, however inaccurate and energy inefficient, working for the sake of completion.

Comment: a "boss is coming"-alert system basically ;)

Comment: @Juri Can you share some details on why RSSI during active connection is not reliable ? I have seen devices using RSSI and able to see relatively consistent RSSI during active connection. In fact Bluetooth uses RSSI to do active dynamic power control

Comment: I'd have to search in my papers for the explanation, but informally speaking, you already gave the explanation: during an active connection Bluetooth applies dynamic power control to save battery life. Each device has a so-called GRPR (Golden Receiver Power Range); depending on whether the RSSI value is above or below that range's min/max, transmission power is increased/decreased. Hence, this influences the RSSI value, meaning during an active connection you may get different RSSI values for the same distance.