# Android Bluetooth: Update RSSI of nearby devices every second

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, rssi

I know it's been a while since the this ->[Android: Update bluetooth rssi every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252242/android-update-bluetooth-rssi-every-second)<- thread started, but i've been digging all around with the same problem and i still don't have a clear solution.

I know the Android API only exposes the RSSI value during the onReceive method after starting a discovery intent. Similarly, i need to update the RSSI value every second (at least), but it takes 12 seconds for discovery intent to end so i can start it again.

Has anyone found a suitable alternative or idea yet?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this one? thank you for your question.

Comment: So, I think it is obvious now that this task is impossible to achieve with the Android API.
I have read in some forums that it may be possible to use the Bluetooth stack directly on the AOSP using a open source stack such as BlueZ.

Comment: Yes, I've made some deep research these two weeks. Bluetooth classic API is impossible for this task, but Bluetooth Ble API is possible.

Comment: Ideally, this could be done in any Bluetooth capable device, and not only in the ones with BLE (the API standard makes it easier, but that does not mean its impossible with some modified Linux code). 
I guess well have to wait to see somebody trying any of this...

Comment: Thank you for your sharings. I feel considering there are particular channels for advertising in Ble, Ble may achieve a higher refresh frequency than the classic.